# On construction of certain sequence of polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis

I am asked to show that there is a sequence of polynomial $p_k(\cdot)$ on $\mathbb{C}$ such that
\begin{equation}
\lim_{k \to \infty}p_k(z)=
\begin{cases}
1 &\textrm{ if } \Re{z}>0\\
0 &\textrm{ if } \Re{z}=0\\
-1 &\textrm{ if } \Re{z}<0\\
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

I do not get the least picture of where I should go ahead, any hint shall be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you allowed to use Runge's theorem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $K_n$ be the compact set $K_n = A_n \cup B_n \cup C_n$, where $A_n = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : \operatorname{Re} z \le -\frac1n, |z| \le n \}$, $B_n = \{ \operatorname{Re} z = 0, |z| \le n \}$ and $C_n = \{ \operatorname{Re} z \ge \frac1n, |z| \le n \}$. Let $f_n$ be a function that equals $-1$ on a neighbourhood of $A_n$, equals $1$ on a neighbourhood of $C_n$ and equals $0$ on a neighbourhood of $B_n$.

Then $f_n$ is holomorphpic on a neighbourhood of $K_n$ and the complement of $K_n$ is connected. By Runge's theorem, we can find a polynomial $p_n$ such that $|p_n - f_n| \le \frac1n$ on $K_n$. Take any $z\in\mathbb C$. When $n$ is large enough, $z$ is in one of $A_n$, $B_n$ or $C_n$, and it's clear that $p_n(z)$ converges to the required thing. (Of course, the convergence is not uniform.)